# Replacing content of html head with jquery and change icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a function that replaces the content of the html page with another page, but then my icon is not showing, title is showing though, here is my js script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('html').html('<head><title>MyTitle</title><link rel="icon" href="/directory/to/my/icon.ico"></link></head><body>MyContent</body>');
    });
});
```

I feel like I am doing nothing wrong, I have included head and close head tag, body and close body tag, and image link correctly too, tested the same link as an image in my body and it does show my icon. I am wondering why does my icon in the tab bar not showing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's `load` method? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @eeya you mean load the <link rel="icon"> tag ? or load the whole content ? For some reasons load is not an option if loading the content, I need to use html().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason replacing whole content of `<html>` element messes up the DOM. If you run your code in real html page and check Developer tools, you'll see that the `title`, `link` and text node are directly in `html` tag without `head` and `body`. Since the link is not officialy in `head` element, the browser doesn't use it. My guess is that `head` and `body` are handled differently from other tags.

Anyway, if you change your code to two separate `.html()` calls, it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('head').html('<title>MyTitle</title><link rel="icon" href="/directory/to/my/icon.ico"></link>');
        $('body').html('MyContent');
    });
});
```

Comment: You sir are my hero. Have been scratching my head so hard, it all make sense now, and thank you for the simple and yet very good solution. Thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0):

what I will suggest is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('html').html('<head><title>MyTitle</title><link rel="icon" id="favicon"></link></head><body>MyContent</body>');
        $("#favicon").attr("href","/directory/to/my/icon.ico");
    });
});
```

Try this.. have not tried it.. but logically should work

Comment: @A Paul, it seems to work for a second but it seems something else quickly changed the icon back to xampp icon, and it seems like coming from an iframe inside my body, but technically the content of iframe should not be able to affect anything in the parent right ?

Comment: No it should not. Unless the iframe is taking the whole page.. or somehow coming top of the parent page.

Comment: Nope the iframe is not taking the whole page, even if it is I think it still shouldn't affect anything in its parent. One more funny thing, so my icon id is 'favicon' but the icon only successfully change to my icon when I use $('#favicons').attr('href', '/directory/to/my/icon.ico'); using $('#favicon') does not work. Already tried erasing all cache and everything, restarting browser and computer, and still it works when selecting $('#favicons'). Not sure why is this.

Comment: Sorry, so it turns out I was using an image with id favicons before, to test the link and changing the src attr, funny thing is, after that, the icon always changed to my icon even when I don't specify the href attr in the link tag, and not doing DOM to change the attr. Only when I include my iframe that the icon change back to xampp icon.

Comment: not sure what exactly your issue is now. Hope you will get it fixed. Let me know if you have any specific question for me

Comment: @A Paul look at @entis answer, it makes sense now.